# Interpretation of a vector of the tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, curvature, vector-fields

Let's consider the description of a 2-sphere $S^2$ without embedding it in the Euclidean space.
From what I understand once I fixed a coordinate system $q_1,q_2$ the tangent basis at a point is $$\frac{\partial}{\partial q^1}, \frac{\partial}{\partial q^2}$$

Following this reasoning if there is a force $\vec F$ applied on a point $P$ of the 2-sphere its expression should be $$\vec F=F_1\frac{\partial}{\partial q^1}+F_2\frac{\partial}{\partial q^2}$$

What's the physical interpretation of $F_1$ and $F_2$?
I supposed they are the intensities of the force measured along the tangent directions to the coordinates lines but it's strange beacuse also the basis vectors in principle could give a contribution to the intensities?

Comment: How is this different from the same question without the differential geometry setting, i.e. about any vector space?

Comment: The fact that $F_1$ and $F_2$ meaning is the one I wrote is just a supposition for me, is it true?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: What "physical interpretation" are you looking for? $F_1$ and $F_2$ give you the component of the force in the direction of the basis vectors $\partial/\partial q^1$ and $\partial/\partial q^2$ respectively.

Comment: Interested in learning more about this ... Is it correct to express F as a linear combination of the tangent basis vectors? It is the same as saying that F lives in the tangent space, but is that right?